# CFG grammar definition

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, formal-languages

Define a CFG (context free language) that generates the language:

L={a^n b^m c^n | n,m>=0}

Can anyone tell me how to address the problem?

My understanding is that L is made of elements like: { aabbbcc } (I assumed that n=2 and m=3)

thanks in advance
Joachim

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework, so I'll just give a few hints.

How might you make the number of a's and c's match in a context-free grammar production?

What kind of production could you use to generate a sequence of b's?

How could these two subproblems be combined into a single context-free grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a context-free grammar that generates the language

```
L1 = {a^nc^n : n >= 0}
```

such as

```
G1 = <{S},{a,c},S,{S -> aSc,S-> λ}>
```

Derivations in `G1` can be characterized as follows:

```
G1 =>1 S        (via S)
   =>* a^nSc^n  (via n >= 0 applications of S -> aSc)
   =>1 a^nc^n   (via S -> λ)
```

The grammar `G1` establishes the required relationship between the number and placement of `a`'s and `c`'s in the language `L1`, then terminates with an application of the rule `S -> λ`.

Consider how a derivation in `G1` is terminated by applying the rule `S -> λ`, and how you might generate a sequence of `m >= 0` `b`'s instead of the empty string. Here is a solution to the problem that is slightly more general. Suppose we have a language `L2` generated by the grammar

```
G2 = <V,N,S2,P>
```

In order to generate strings in `L2` surrounded by an equal number of `a`'s and `c`'s, the rules of `G1` might be augmented as follows to obtain a grammar `G1'`:

```
G1' = <{S} ∪ V,{a,c} ∪ N,S,{S -> aSc,S -> S2} ∪ {P}>
```

To solve your problem, let `L2` be the language `{b}*` and `G2` the regular grammar that generates it.